# Delete \n from variable

Tags: bash, date, unix

I need to delete de \n in the return of date.

Why does this work?

```
     NAME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" | tr -d "\n")
```

And this doesn't

```
     NAME=date +"%Y-%m-%d"
     NAME2=$(echo $NAME | tr -d "\n")
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly remove a newline: the `$(...)` construct does it for you. See in action: `d=$(date); printf "%s" "$d" | od -c` versus `date | od -c`

Answer (score 4):

`NAME=date +"%Y-%m-%d"` does not mean to assign the output of date to NAME. It tries to run a command named `+%Y-%m-%d` with a variable `NAME` in its environment.

To capture the output you have to use `$(..)` like in your first example:

```
NAME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Also note that trailing line feeds are automatically stripped by command expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the variables in shell and make sure to use proper command substitution syntax:

```
NAME="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
NAME2=$(echo "$NAME" | tr -d "\n")
```

Comment: @user3013172: Without quoting shell interprets your assignment as 2 different arguments.